# what is the best and easiest to draw a multi bar chart in php

Tags: php, charts

i want to display the results of students scores in a multi-vertical bar chart (red bar for correct , green bar for false) for each question,, 
i already tried Google chart, but it gives me result in this way:[link text](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=400x400&cht=bvg&chtt=sheet1&chdl=Corret%20|False%20&chxt=y,y&chxl=0:|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|1:|+0%|10%|20%|30%|40%|50%|60%|70%|80%|90%|100%&chg=25,10,1&chco=8dcb41,e3372e&chd=t:33.3,100,66.7,33.3|100,33.3,66.7,100&chxr=&chxr.png)

note: the bars that reached the top , should not be at top ,,  only because they have the highest value  (75%), Google chart makes it at top which i don't want..

any suggestions about how to draw simple vertical bar chart with php

Comment: You can tell Google Charts what you want the max height to be. Also, in your chd (data) var you do have a "100" in every place where it's reaching the top....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/
http://jpgraph.net/

Answer (score 0):

you could just build it with tables/divs and css... 1px = 1% etc. - you can also use jpgraph or any other javascript based charts system like jscharts.com